# Is there a description of the underlying space of an embedded submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a real differentiable manifold, and $E$ a subset of $X$.  There is at most one differentiable structure on $E$ such that $E$ has the induced topology, the inclusion map is smooth, and the map on all the tangent spaces $T_p(E) \rightarrow T_p(X)$ is injective.  If this is the case, then $E$ is said to be a submanifold of $X$.

I have seen examples of closed submanifolds, or locally closed submanifolds.  Is there a necessary condition we can give about the kind of subspaces of $X$ which are submanifolds?  For example, locally closed.  If we replace "differentiable" by "analytic," does the answer change?

My motivation comes from algebraic geometry, where the underlying space of subschemes of a scheme are specifically defined to be locally closed.

Comment: Your working definition is actually that of an *immersed* (as opposed to *embedded*) submanifold, so the image certainly need not be even locally closed. Consider the "dense line on the torus," i.e., the image of the line $y=ax$ when you project $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$, with $a\notin\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I meant embedded submanifold, I have edited

Answer (score 2):

(Embedded) submanifolds are locally closed.  The constant rank theorem tells us that if $E$ is an $n-k$ dimensional submanifold of a manifold $X$, then for every $p \in E$, there exists a chart $(U,\phi)$ of $X$ containing $p$, such that

$$\phi(U \cap E) = \phi(U) \cap \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$$

where $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is identified with the subspace $(x_1, ... , x_{n-k},0, ... , 0)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Since $\phi(U) \cap \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is closed in $\phi(U)$, $U \cap E$ is closed in $U$.

So $E$ is covered by open sets $U$ of $X$ such that for each $U$, $E \cap U$ is closed in $U$.  This means that $E$ is locally closed in $X$.

Comment: It seems this does not use the fact charts are onto *open* subsets of Euclidean space, right?

Comment: I guess not $\space$